# How to search for an docker image in multiple private registries

Tags: docker, docker-registry

When we are searching for an image in our private registry we need to specify the host "docker search 10.10.10.10:5000/apache"
If we execute "docker search apache" docker is looking for an image only in the official docher hub registry.
Our use case:

```
FROM organization/apache
# .....
# custom instructions
```

We want to search this image in our registry(without providing registry host), and if it is not found use public docker hub registry.
Is it possible to configure docker client to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you actually want to do is set up a Docker mirror: https://docs.docker.com/registry/recipes/mirror/

So the first time you pull an image, it will come from the Hub, but subsequent requests will be handled locally.

Comment: I am not sure that answers the question. With a Docker mirror setup, will a search/pull for `some/image` search _all_ of the configured mirrors + the official docker hub? I.e. is it even possible to refer to a private image on a private registry (with proprietary software that you cannot make public on docker hub) using just `some/image` or does it always have to include the registry hostname like `my-private-registry.com/some/image` ?

Comment: This is an old question, but I guess I was trying to solve the problem rather than directly answer the question. I'm really not sure what `docker search` will do when a registry mirror is configured.

Answer (score 0):

any docker command (`docker ps` or `docker stats`) is in fact a call to the docker API, so you can do, instead of a `docker search apache` a `curl "http://docker.example.com:2375/images/search?term=apache"  |  python-mjson.tool` so check the doc https://docs.docker.com/reference/api/docker_remote_api/ . Your script can first look with the previous curl command, test the result and if not found search the official registry hub http://registry.hub.docker.com/